# DRY code, two equal functions

Tags: php, class, dry

I have `Banks` class and I need to code two methods: `addBalance(value)` and `removeBalance(value)`, the only thing that changes is the operator. I don't want to pass it by parameter..

I thought to use a third function, then, addBalance and removeBalance would just to call it.

Ok, so my logic is correct, then, I'm gonna to need to pass the operator (+ or -) to manageBalance.. how should I pass it? I mean, string, integer, what is the best clean way?

Comment: great! go for it... what's your question?

Comment: ... and? What's your question?

Comment: Ok, so my logic is correct, then, I'm gonna to need to pass the operator (+ or -) to `manageBalance`.. how should I pass it? I mean, string, integer?

Comment: In addition to actually asking a question, it would be helpful for you to show the existing code.

Comment: If you only want one function why not call it `adjustBalance($val)` and when you call it to add to balance pass a positive number, and to  remove from balance just pass a negative number.

Comment: IMO having 2 functions is the cleanest way. Your code will be more readable and understandable for anyone looking at it

Comment: Alright, having 2 functions, ok.. so these functions only call another one that really do the job, I need to pass + or - to this function, should I pass it by boolean (true -> remove, false -> add) or something else? I mean, I want the best perfomance way

Comment: Performance is no concern here, maintainability is. Go with 2 functions